# ImageView not showing on launch screen

Tags: ios, swift

I've created two launch screens now trying to get this to work.

The launch screen is simply a company logo in the middle and then a copyright notice at the bottom.

The copyright notice always show up when I launch the app but the logo is never visible.

I have set the constraints on the logo and when I change the dimensions of the `xib` the logo always stays where I need it.

I have checked the `Copy Bundle Resources` and both the logo `png` file and `xib` are present.

Im at a loss here, any ideas?

**View Hierarchy**

[image]

**Image Constraints**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure its the right launch screen loading? The default launch screen contains copy right notice by default on a plain white background.

Comment: @NSNoob ya it is. if i make changes to the text they are reflected.

Comment: Can you show us the View hierarchy of the said launch screen? Just want to make sure no other view is hiding that `UIImageView`

Comment: @NSNoob ive updated my question

Comment: Good, What are the constraints on UIImageView? They might be forcing the image view to go out of view. Also what is the frame for the copyright notice? Is it well off the frame of imageView?

Comment: The yellow arrow in the upper right corner of the screenshot you posted means you have some constraint issues. Try resolving those.

Comment: @AaronBrager I resolved the issues. Still no luck.

Comment: @NSNoob updated question again.

Comment: These constraints seem sketchy. Just to be sure, can you change the constraint of imageview making it align center-x to copyright label? Make it instead `center horizontally in container`? Then put a breakpoint in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions ` before returning YES. This is what I am getting now http://imgur.com/axUjgqM from the information i have

Comment: In Interface Builder, click on the triangle in the bottom right of the editing window and click "Update Frames" under "All Views" to see if your constraints are causing a view to be out of frame

Comment: @quark the frames are already all updated

Comment: @NSNoob tried it. still no luck

Comment: @NSNoob I changed it to another image and it shows up. Could the transparency be doing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the image to `images.xcassets` and then using that image in the image view solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add images into project folder as well as images.xcassets solved my issue